# Encoding UTF8 string to ISO-8859-1 String (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I need to convert UTF8 string to ISO-8859-1 string using VB.NET.

Any example?

---

*emphasized text*I have tried Latin function and not runs. I receive incorrect string.

My case is that I need to send SMS using API.

Now I have this code:

```
        baseurl = "http://www.myweb.com/api/sendsms.php"
        client = New WebClient
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)")
        client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
        client.QueryString.Add("user", user)
        client.QueryString.Add("password", pass)
        client.QueryString.Add("alias", myAlias)
        client.QueryString.Add("dest",  mobile)
        textoSms = Me.mmTexto.Text
        textoSms = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textoSms)
        client.QueryString.Add("message", textoSms)
        data = client.OpenRead(baseurl)
        reader = New StreamReader(data)
        s = reader.ReadToEnd()
        data.Close()
        reader.Close()
```

But not runs...I receive incorrect messages. For example

if I write: *mañana* returns *maa ana*

If I write *aigüa* returns *aiga*

Comment: none. I did not get any solution that worked well at 100%. if not I would have marked it as solved...sorry...

Comment: No, I asked, what have you tried? This "question" is just asking for someone to tell you what to do, with no evidence of prior research.

Comment: I do not understand what you said .... only I know that question was opened 3 years ago!

Comment: I don't see how what I said was complicated or difficult to understand.

Comment: Are you saying that the answer by Jon Skeet did not in fact answer your question? Because if it didn't, the question doesn't make any sense. UTF8 and ISO-8859-1 are *encodings* of Unicode text. In .NET, a string is always in Unicode format in memory, it's only when you want to convert it to a byte-array (usually because you need to store it in a binary file or send it over the network) that you involve encoding it. Jon Skeets answer was to the point and correct for the question at hand. If not, I'm closing this as too-localized since clearly the question is wrong then.

Comment: my excuses. OK, Jon's example works well .... could be a problem with my webservice provider. Now I manage and replace some characters before sending them and works well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
Dim converted as Byte() = Encoding.Convert(utf8, Encoding.UTF8, _
                                           Encoding.GetEncoding(28591))
```

That assumes that when you say "UTF8 string" you mean "binary data which is the UTF-8 representation of some text". If you mean something else, please specify :)

Note that ISO-8859-1 only represents a tiny proportion of full Unicode. IIRC, you'll end up with "?" for any character from the source data which isn't available in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Thanks for the "?" reference, it just happened to save me today.

Comment: @jonskeet, I take issue with your use of the word "tiny".  Technically you may be correct but it's also true that a huge portion of Unicode is irrelevant for most applications.  There is a list of around 30 modern languages with "Complete Coverage" in ISO--8859-1 on this page.  Spoiler: one of them is Spanish: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Comment: @JoelFan: Unless someone writing in Spanish also wants to include an emoji, or the name of someone who *isn't* Spanish, or a word from a different language etc. I consider an application which is limited to ISO-8859-1 to be pretty problematic in the modern world. Whenever a developer has a choice, I'd advise using UTF-8.

Comment: I agree with you there 100%, but I just felt the terminology used was just a smidge misleading

Comment: @JoelFan: I stand by it, really. It's a very small portion of the full Unicode set, and with emoji being so popular (and plenty of other use cases) I think it would only be suitable for a very small subset of applications.

Comment: @JonSkeet, You may be interested in my recent question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46006463/system-io-file-readalltext-not-throwing-exception-for-invalid-encoding

Answer (score 3):

The encoding ISO-8859-1 is more commonly called Latin-1.  You can get this encoding by doing the following

```
Dim latin1 = Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(&H6FAF)
```

The full conversion can be done by the following

```
Public Function ConvertUtf8ToLatin1(Dim bytes As Byte()) As Bytes()
  Dim latin1 = Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(&H6FAF)
  Return Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, latin1, bytes)
End Function
```

**EDIT**

As Jon pointed out, it may be easier for people to remember the decimal number 28591 rather than the hex number &H6FAF.

Comment: Why use &H6FAF when the decimal literal 28591 is rather easier to remember (if you know you're after 8859-1)?

Comment: @Jon, cause I used reflector and it was outputing hex numbers :)

Answer (score 1):

Because `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")` does not support `ñ` is my guess, in that case you need to use another encoding type for you SMS.

Please read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.convert.aspx

Try this with the variable "input" as the UTF-8 String;

VB.NET:

```
Dim result As Byte() = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), input);
```

C#:

```
byte[] result = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this should be posted here but i made a small function in C# to check if a string support the target encoding type.

Hope it can be of any help...

```
/// <summary>
/// Function for checking if a string can support the target encoding type
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">The text to check</param>
/// <param name="targetEncoding">The target encoding</param>
/// <returns>True if the encoding supports the string and false if it does not</returns>
public bool SupportsEncoding(string text, Encoding targetEncoding)
{
    var btext = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
    var bencodedtext = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, targetEncoding, btext);

    var checktext = targetEncoding.GetString(bencodedtext);
    return checktext == text;
}

//Call the function demo with ISO-8859-1/Latin-1
if (SupportsEncoding("some text...", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
{
    //The encoding is supported
}
else
{
    //The encoding is not supported 
}
```