# Download UTF-8 web page into String

Tags: vb.net, string, utf-8

This is a newbie question.

I read [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499397/encoding-utf8-string-to-iso-8859-1-string-vb-net) to download a web page whose contents is coded in UTF-8. The page is then converted into a byte array, while I'm using a String to read contents from the page.

I need to turn UTF-8 into Latin1/ANSI since that's what RichText and MessageBox seem to use (I'm getting funny characters).

Is there a more direct way to donwload a UTF-8 page and convert it into ANSI/Latin1?

Thank you.

---

Edit: When callig MessageBox, accented characters are not shown as expected:

Content = CStr(e.Result)

'ThÃ©Ã¢tre, MÃ©tro
  MessageBox.Show(Content)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String` in .NET uses unicode all the way, so you should not have to convert it *to* something. The important thing is that when you download the page, you need to make sure that you mark that you load the data *from* a UTF-8 source.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx) has a sample on loading UTF-8 encoded data into a string:

```
Private Function ReadAuthor(binary_file As Stream) As String
     Dim encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
     ' Read string from binary file with UTF8 encoding
     Dim buffer(30) As Byte
     binary_file.Read(buffer, 0, 30)
     Return encoding.GetString(buffer)
End Function
```

### Update

When using `WebClient.DownloadString` the conversion to a string takes place automatically and code similar to the one above is not needed. The automatic conversion uses the encoding specified by `WebClient.Encoding`, so the problem should be solved by setting the WebClient object's encoding property to UTF-8:

```
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The async routine provides the web page in a DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs variable: How can I turn this into a stream?

Comment: See my update on how to specify the encoding used by `WebClient.DownloadString`.