# Set string encoding to ISO-8859-1

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, encoding, utf-8, visual-studio-2010

I have a string that is encoded with UTF-8, I would like to convert its encoding to the `ISO-8859-1`. Is that possible to do?

Comment: What you would like to do with this string?

Comment: I'm generating SQL query (its hard to understand, but I need to change the encoding in order to have Polish special characters displaying correctly in my game. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499397/encoding-utf8-string-to-iso-8859-1-string-vb-net

Comment: The string is default in UNICODE (not UTF-8), so char encoding will be problematic on display. But I do not know how you display your code. Could you show it? Polish chars are sometimes really hard to display;)

Comment: @Garath: UTF-8 is an encoding of Unicode. Strings in .NET use UTF-16 , which is another encoding of Unicode.

Comment: @Lucas: how do you have a UTF-8 encoded string in the first place?

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are of course right.