# Adding accented file name with VBA in outlook message

Tags: vba, outlook, character-encoding

Saving a file attachment in an Outlook mail item with the VBA method `Attachment.SaveAsFile()` call produces the expected result (file saved with same filename on the filesystem), even for file names with **non-ASCII** characters.

However, VBA apparently stores the file name in a **16-bit composite format** `String` where accented letters are stored as a (letter, accent) pair. I can't find a way to output the string inside the message body with accented letters showing up as one glyph ("é") instead of two ("e´").

Concretely, the attachment is properly saved under the correct file name on disk when using the following code:

```
' Save the Outlook attachment
oAttachment.SaveAsFile (sTempFileLocation)
```

This results in a file being written to the folder specified in `sTempFileLocation` and the file name complies with the way it appears in the Outlook message (accents, non-ASCII characters etc).

However, when retrieving and manipulating the file name, it appears that a 16-bit composite internal representation of special characters is used. This means that the file name **"à présent.txt"** is displayed as **"a` pre´sent.txt"** (accented characters are represented with the character + the accent in 2 consecutive bytes).

For instance:

```
sAttachmentName = fso.getfilename(sTempFileLocation)
Debug.Print ("Attachment name = [" & sAttachmentName & "]")
```

will result in:

```
Attachment name = [a` pre´sent.txt]
```

There is little information available on this matter, all I found so far was [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) describing the `MultiByteToWideChar()` function. From there it appears that the 16-bit internal VBA rendering happens implcitly and is even computer dependent (depending on code page and locale in use).

Here follows a self-contained minimalistic example that tries to save the email attachments of the first selected message to your **My Documents** folder unless it already exists:

```
Sub SaveMessageAttachments()
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oSelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim aMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim fso As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    ' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
    Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    ' Get the collection of selected objects.
    Set oSelection = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    If oSelection Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Select the 1st mail item in the current selection
    Set aMail = oSelection.item(1)

    Dim sAttachmentFolder  As String
    ' Get the path to your "My Documents" folder
    sAttachmentFolder = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim oAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim lItemAttachmentCount As Long

    Set oAttachments = aMail.Attachments
    lItemAttachmentCount = oAttachments.Count

    If (lItemAttachmentCount > 0) Then
        Dim lAttachmentIndex As Long
        For lAttachmentIndex = 1 To lItemAttachmentCount
            Dim oAttachment As Outlook.attachment
            Set oAttachment = oAttachments.item(lAttachmentIndex)
            Dim sFileName As String
            sFileName = oAttachment.FileName
            If LenB(sFileName) > 0 Then
                Dim sFilePath As String
                sFilePath = sAttachmentFolder & "\" & sFileName
                If fso.fileexists(sFilePath) Then
                    MsgBox "Cannot save attachment " & lAttachmentIndex & vbCr _
                        & "File already exists: " & vbCr _
                        & sFilePath, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
                Else
                    If MsgBox("Saving atachment " & lAttachmentIndex & "?" & vbCr _
                        & "Save location: " & vbCr & sFilePath, _
                        vbQuestion + vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
                        ' Save the attachment to the temporary folder
                        oAttachment.SaveAsFile (sFilePath)
                        Dim sAttachmentName As String
                        sAttachmentName = fso.getfilename(sFilePath)

                        Dim lAttachmentLength As Long
                        lAttachmentLength = fso.getfile(sFilePath).size

                        Dim sURL As String
                        sURL = "file://" & Replace(sFilePath, "\", "/")

                        MsgBox "Attachment " & lAttachmentIndex _
                            & " saved as: " & sAttachmentName & vbCr _
                            & "Size: " & lAttachmentLength & vbCr _
                            & "URL = " & sURL, _
                            vbInformation + vbOKOnly
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next lAttachmentIndex
    End If
End Sub
```

As you will see, the `SaveMessageAttachments()` subroutine correctly saves the file to the filesystem, with the proper file name. However, Outlook dialogs (as well as when trying to write the attachment file name or URL to the message body in VBA) will always render the file names having accents differently. Please give it a try with an Outlook message having an attachment named e.g. **"à présent.txt"**).

What is strange, however, is that if I try to paste `sURL` in the message body, although the URL is incorrectly written (2 character decomposition of accented letters) Outlook seems to find and open the file.

How can I transform this accented string (`sAttachmentName`) with VBA in order to correctly paste it (**"à présent.txt"** instead of **"a` pre´sent.txt"**) into the message body?

Comment: Meanwhile I have been exploring [identifying the system locale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500552/vba-for-excel-2010-2013-how-to-identify-the-system-locale), [determining regional settings in VBA](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?287517-Determining-regional-setting-in-VBA-code&p=1676041&viewfull=1#post1676041), [encoding utf-8 to iso-8859-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499397/encoding-utf8-string-to-iso-8859-1-string-vb-net) but I always stumble on VB.NET solutions that don't work in VBA. How can I convert from `LOCALE_IDEFAULTCODEPAGE` to the email body's charset?

Comment: Another example (but for ASP) I found is [Convert string between windows-1250 and iso-8859-2 (or utf-8) charsets, ASP](http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/cm436.htm). I don't know how to make this conversion work with VBA.

Comment: Apparently plain text messages don't suffer this problem. It seems it's the HTML messages that have this charset (codepage) problem.

Comment: It appears that it is **impossible** to get this working with VBA. I tried all possible combinations between character code pages and [the charset conversion code found here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/convert-string-one-codepage-another-t3082087.html), and it never works.